# link_to_remote is not working in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using link_to_remote for answering the quiz one by one. in that i want the checked radio button. but when i clicked the button and clicked next it doesnt change,the spinner loads only

```
<div class = "y">
<% form_for @answer do |f|%>
<div class = "label_field_pair">
<label for "questions">
  <%= @ans.ques %>
</label>  
</div> <br>
<div class = "label_field_pair2">
<label for "options">
  <div id = "option-1">
    <%= radio_button_tag :answer, :ans1%><%= @ans.ans1 %>
  </div><br>
  <div id = "option-2">
    <%= radio_button_tag :answer, :ans2%><%= @ans.ans2 %>
  </div><br>
  <div id = "option-3">
    <%= radio_button_tag :answer, :ans3%><%= @ans.ans3 %>
  </div><br>
  <div id = "option-4">
    <%= radio_button_tag :answer, :ans4%><%= @ans.ans4  %>
  </div><br>
</label>
</div>
  <%= link_to_remote "Next", 
    :before => "Element.show('loader')",
    :success => "Element.hide('loader')",
    :url=>{:controller=>"answers", :action=>"next"},
    :with => "'answer='+$F(answer)+'&passed_question=#{@ans.id}&'+'&exam_group_id=#{@exam_group.id}&'"
  %> 
</div> 
<% end %> 
</div>
```

in that i want to get the value of checked radio button in :with statement...
thanks in advance please help me out

Comment: What version of rails?

Comment: rails version is 2.3.5

Comment: Using 2.3.5 is **extremely hazardous** if you have a public site. You should update immediately to 2.3.18. There are a number of remote vulnerabilities that are very serious.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
<%= link_to "Next", your_path, :remote => true, ... %>
```